# Generic method that returns List<T> instead returns List<dynamic>

Tags: dart, generics

I tried writing a simple generic method that would iteratively copy a nested `List`, for example a `List<List<int>>`. But unfortunately, the recursive call seems to always return `List<dynamic>`, so I get the following error

```
The argument type List<dynamic> can't be assigned to the parameter type T
```

```
List<T> listDeepCopy<T>(List<T> list){
  List<T> newList = List<T>();

  list.forEach((value) {
    if( value is List ){
      newList.add(listDeepCopy(value));  // <-- listDeepCopy() always returns List<dynamic>
    }
    else{
      newList.add(value);      
    }
  });

  return newList;
}
```

So if I call

```
List<List<int>> list = [[1,2],[3,4]];
List<List<int>> copy = listDeepCopy(list);
```

`T` is `List<int>`

`value` is `T` - i.e. `List<int>`

`listDeepCopy(value)` should equal `listDeepCopy<List<int>>`, which would return a `List<int>`, which should be possible to add to `newList`, which is a `List<List<int>>`

Where am I going wrong here, and how can I make something like this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably would implement it as:

```dart
List<T> listDeepCopy<T>(List<T> list) {
  var copy = list.toList();
  for (var i = 0; i < copy.length; i += 1) {
    var element = copy[i];
    if (element is List) {
      copy[i] = listDeepCopy(element) as T;
    }
  }
  return copy;
}

void main() {
  List<List<int>> list = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
  ];
  List<List<int>> copy = listDeepCopy(list);

  list[0][0] = 99;
  print(copy); // Prints: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
}
```

A problem with your approach is that Dart cannot properly infer the generic type parameter for that recursive `listDeepCopy(value)` call. `value` is of type `T` that is known to be a `List` (which is shorthand for `List<dynamic>`), and I am not aware of a way to extract the static element type. (Maybe @lrn will see this and provide a better, more complete explanation.)

In such a case, it's better to rely on polymorphism by calling a method on the `List` that returns a copy of itself: `.toList()`.

(As an example where this matters, consider a shallow copy scenario:

```dart
List<T> shallowCopy1<T>(List<T> list) => <T>[...list];

List<T> shallowCopy2<T>(List<T> list) => list.toList();

extension StaticType<T> on T {
  Type get staticType => T;
}

void main() {
  List<num> list = <int>[1, 2, 3];
  var copy1 = shallowCopy1(list);
  var copy2 = shallowCopy2(list);

  print('original: staticType: ${list.staticType}, runtimeType: ${list.runtimeType}');
  print('copy1: staticType: ${copy1.staticType}, runtimeType: ${copy1.runtimeType}');
  print('copy2: staticType: ${copy2.staticType}, runtimeType: ${copy2.runtimeType}');
}
```

Although both copies preserve the *static* type of the original `List`, only `copy2` preserves the object's actual (runtime) type.  A proper copy depends on the *runtime* type of the object being copied, and the only robust way to do that is for the object to create a copy of itself.)

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems to work for both `List` and `Set`! Now, if only there was a way to achieve the same for `Map`... but from what I've found so far, it seems impossible (for nested `Map`s)?

Comment: @Magnus Yeah, I can't think of a way to do it for `Map`s since `Map` does not provide a method to make a shallow copy of itself without depending on the static type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it the way you are trying to do it.

The problem is that `deepClone<T>` converts a `List<dynamic>` to a `List<T>` (which is fine) and then tries to convert elements that are themselves lists into typed list ... but you don't know the type.
In effect, when you check that `value is List`, you don't know what kind of list to convert it to.
There are two cases:

- Either `T` is `List<X>` or `Iterable<X>` for some type `X`, but you have *no way* to get your hands on that `X`. Dart doesn't allow you to destructure types at runtime.
- Or `T` is `Object` or another general supertype with no "list element" type inside it, and then you simply do not have any information about what `List` type to convert the nested list to. (That's actually the simplest case, because then you should simply not `deepClone` the list at all).

There is a way to figure out which case you are in (`<T>[] is List<Iterable<Object?>>`), but it won't help you in the former case, unless you want to do an exhaustive search of all the possible types that `X` might be.

What I'd do instead is to *build* a converter, instead of using a single function.

```dart
abstract class Cloner<T> {
  const factory Cloner() = _ValueCloner<T>;
  T clone(dynamic source);
  Cloner<List<T>> get list => _ListCloner(this);
}
abstract class _BaseCloner<T> implements Cloner<T> {
  const _BaseCloner();
  Cloner<List<T>> get list => _ListCloner<T>(this);
}
class _ValueCloner<T> extends _BaseCloner<T> {
  const _ValueCloner();
  T clone(dynamic source) => source as T;
}
class _ListCloner<T> extends _BaseCloner<List<T>> {
  final Cloner<T> _base;
  _ListCloner(this._base);
  List<T> clone(dynamic source) =>
     <T>[for (var o in source as List<dynamic>) _base.clone(o)];
}
```

Then, if you actually know the type of the data, you can build your cloner as:

```dart
var typedList =
    Cloner<int>().list.list.clone(
        <dynamic>[<dynamic>[1, 2], <dynamic>[3, 4]]);
```

which yields a `List<List<int>>` with the value `<List<int>>[<int>[1, 2], <int>[3, 4]]`.